# Ubuntu from a USB drive

Tags: laptop, usb-drive

I wish to run Ubuntu from my thumbdrive. Is there a "Flavor" that you would recommend? I truly thank you!

Larry

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Ubuntu version is a matter of personal preference. It is easy enough to download a few different flavors and test drive for yourself, before making your choice. It only takes five minutes to make a Persistent install.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Here](https://releases.ubuntu.com/) is the official list of *versions* currently avaliable.

[18.04](/questions/tagged/18.04) is the LTS (Long-term support) release currently being phased-out. It is very stable, but you might want to look at newer options.

I am currently using [19.10](/questions/tagged/19.10), and have not encountered problems.

[20.04](/questions/tagged/20.04) LTS just released officially (see the [announcement](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2020-April/004969.html)). As this is an LTS release, I assume it is stable, but I have not tried it yet.

#### [*"Flavors"*](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) = desktop environments...

You have many choices when it comes to this. It pretty much comes down to opinion. The desktop environment provides the "look" of Ubuntu. You can install just about any DE on any version, but GNOME is the default that comes with the current vanilla downloads.

If this is your first time, I would recommend starting with the default option. You can change the DE after you have installed Ubuntu if you want to try something else that you see online.